# Stop .on() event and re init after function has complete

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get multiple wysiwyg tabs (buttons) to all work in unison in my Wordpress page editor.

I am half way there with targeting all the correct tabs to triggered with a click. The `.each()` loop is working fine.

I have created functions `switch_tmce()` and `switch_html()` for the `.on()` which i'm now binding like this..

```
$(document).on('click', '.switch-tmce', switch_tmce() );
$(document).on('click', '.switch-html', switch_html() );
```

What I'm trying do is set the `.on()` event, then when the event is fired by clicking the button, I want to stop event temporally so that is not fired again while each tab is being looped and click triggered.

Once all the button clicks have been triggered, I want then re-init the current event so it can be used again. I've set a live demo in the code below.

The console log should always show every button with matching class that doesn't have the parent `.clones` when a button is clicked.

**Update working code below, thanks [@charlietfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl)**

```js
// document ready
(function ($) {
    
    // visual tmce switch
    function switch_tmce() {

        console.clear();

        // temporary disable all visual tmce switch
        $(document).off('click', '.switch-tmce', switch_tmce );

        // for each wysiwyg tmce switch button
        $('.switch-tmce', '.acf-field-wysiwyg').not(this).each(function (i) {

            // if this does not have a parent clones
            if (!$(this).closest('.clones').length) {

                // trigger the switch
                $(this).click();
                
                console.log($(this)[0]);

            }

        });

        // reinit on all visual tmce switch
        $(document).on('click','.switch-tmce', switch_tmce );

    }

    // raw html switch
    function switch_html() {
        
        console.clear();

        // temporary disable all raw html switch
        $(document).off('click', '.switch-html', switch_html );

        // for each wysiwyg html switch button
        $('.switch-html','.acf-field-wysiwyg').not(this).each(function(i) {

            // if this does not have a parent clones
            if(! $(this).closest('.clones').length ) {

                // trigger the switch
                $(this).click();
                
                console.log($(this)[0]);

            }

        });

        // reinit on all raw html switch
        $(document).on('click','.switch-html', switch_html );

    }
    
    // on visual tmce switch
    $(document).on('click', '.switch-tmce', switch_tmce );

    // on raw html switch
    $(document).on('click', '.switch-html', switch_html );


})(jQuery);
```

```css
BUTTON {
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
}  

.clones {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="acf-field-wysiwyg">
  <button class="switch-tmce" id="1-tmce">Visual</button>
  <button class="switch-html" id="1-html">Text</button>
</div>

<div class="acf-field-wysiwyg">
  <button class="switch-tmce" id="2-tmce">Visual</button>
  <button class="switch-html" id="2-html">Text</button>
</div>

<div class="acf-field-wysiwyg">
  <button class="switch-tmce" id="3-tmce">Visual</button>
  <button class="switch-html" id="3-html">Text</button>
</div>

<div class="acf-field-wysiwyg">
  <button class="switch-tmce" id="4-tmce">Visual</button>
  <button class="switch-html" id="4-html">Text</button>
</div>

<div class="clones">
  <div class="acf-field-wysiwyg">
    <button id="clone-tmce" class="switch-tmce">Visual</button>
    <button id="clone-html" class="switch-html">Text</button>
  </div>
</div>  


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Don't invoke `switch_tmce` , pass tthe function reference instead of the result of calling the function  ... `$(document).on('click', '.switch-tmce', switch_tmce );`. Also use of `each` loop in `not()` doesn't make sense. Not sure what is expected there

Comment: Thank you so much man you helped me out big time. I've just updated my code above and it's working sweet now. With the `.not()` I am excluding the button which is being clicked. Seems to be working.

Comment: My bad...I misread the closing `)` in that `not()`...disregard my comment above as I consume more morning coffee Note you could simplify to `not(this)` without wrapping `this` in another `$()` call

Comment: Yeah that is a great shout, updated code with `this` and works great. Thank you! If you wana drop an answer with my code above I can revert back to my old code. If not no worries and thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are invoking the handler functions at run time instead of passing them as reference for the handlers of the click listeners

Simply remove the `()` that invoke them

```
$(document).on('click', '.switch-tmce', switch_tmce );// function reference not result of calling function
```